# TextArea saving to MySQL with php and showing out in html

Tags: javascript, php

I want to save value in a textarea to MySQL database using PHP. And then I want to pass it to a variable in javascript
The value in a textare could be like this:

```
Hi I'm Son!! 
Nice to meet you
```

**So my 1st question is: How can I add the text to my database using php with the absence of special chars? (Like which encoding...)**

I'm gonna pass that text through an event of a hyperlink click. It's something like this:

```
    <?php
    echo '<a href="#" onclick=passExample('$myText')>Something</a>';
    ?>
```

After all, the javascript I coded is like this:

```
function passExample(Exa){
            $("#ExampleShow").empty();
            var node = document.createElement("p");
            if (Exa=='') Exa=' (No example)';
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(html_entity_decode(Exa));
            node.appendChild(textnode);
            document.getElementById("ExampleShow").appendChild(node);
        }
```

However, the result is not the way I wanted it to be. Line breaks are missing. And if I type some character like ''", it results in errors. **How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="passExample(\''.addslashes($myText).'\')";>Something</a>';
```

also read:

- [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) (for clearing too much data from user input).
- [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines) (for using php output in javascript and escaping it).